# How to use a labelled column in sqlalchemy filter?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to use the labelled column in sqlalchemy filter. for eg:

```
db.session.query(
    PartMaster.name,
    PartMaster.description,
    PartTracker.actual_length,
    func.sum(PartTracker.quantity).label('quantity')
).join(PartTracker).group_by(
    PartTracker.part_master_id,PartTracker.actual_length
).all()
```

I need the result with `quantity > 0`. please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL if you want to filter rows by result, you need to use HAVING instructions.

So in your case:

```
db.session.query(
    PartMaster.name,
    PartMaster.description,
    PartTracker.actual_length,
    func.sum(PartTracker.quantity).label('quantity')
).join(PartTracker).group_by(
    PartTracker.part_master_id,PartTracker.actual_length
).having(
    func.sum(PartTracker.quantity) > 0
)
```

Example from [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.having)

Comment: I guess there is no need for .label('quantity'). Right?