# Filter by labelled column in union'd SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Realizing the title is nearly equivalent to [How to use a labelled column in sqlalchemy filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825773/how-to-use-a-labelled-column-in-sqlalchemy-filter) I believe this is a separate issue.

To vastly simplify my issue: Say I have two queries that each return a subset of the result I want, that I union together:

```
initial_task = "initial_task"
scheduled_task = "scheduled_task"

initial = session.query(Task.task_id,
                        User.signup_date.label('due_date'),
                        literal(initial_task).label('type'))\
                 .join(Task.user)

schedule = session.query(Task.task_id,
                        Schedule.due_date.label('due_date'),
                        literal(scheduled_task).label('type'))\
                  .join(Task.schedule)

tasks = initial.union_all(schedule)
```

And to be clear: I realize this example could be rewritten without the union; my actual use case has five separate queries with almost nothing in common outside of the result being coercible to this normal format.

How can I filter `tasks` to only include tasks that are due after April 1st 2017? Conceptually, something like:

```
tasks.filter(tasks.c.due_date >= datetime(2017, 4, 1))
```

The main issue is I can't figure out how to refer to the `due_date` column in a general way. Everything I try from the docs seems to be talking about the lower level API, and on the ORM layer leads to:

```
'Query' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Query.union_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union_all) method produces a new `Query` instance, which is a bit different from the `CompoundSelect` produced by the [`sql.expression.union_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all) construct, as you've noted. You could use [`literal_column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) to filter the query:

```
In [18]: tasks.filter(literal_column('due_date') >= datetime(2017, 4, 1))
Out[18]: <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query at 0x7f1d2e191b38>

In [19]: print(_)
SELECT anon_1.task_id AS anon_1_task_id, anon_1.due_date AS anon_1_due_date, anon_1.type AS anon_1_type 
FROM (SELECT task.id AS task_id, user.signup_date AS due_date, ? AS type 
FROM task JOIN user ON task.id = user.task_id UNION ALL SELECT task.id AS task_id, schedule.due_date AS due_date, ? AS type 
FROM task JOIN schedule ON task.id = schedule.task_id) AS anon_1 
WHERE due_date >= ?
```

On the other hand you could just filter the parts of the union separately on their respective date columns.

Finally, you could wrap your union in a subquery, if that is closer to your actual goal (hidden by your simplified example):

```
In [26]: tasks_sq = tasks.subquery()

In [27]: session.query(tasks_sq).\
    ...:     filter(tasks_sq.c.due_date >= datetime(2017, 4, 1))
Out[27]: <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query at 0x7f1d2e1d4828>

In [28]: print(_)
SELECT anon_1.task_id AS anon_1_task_id, anon_1.due_date AS anon_1_due_date, anon_1.type AS anon_1_type 
FROM (SELECT anon_2.task_id AS task_id, anon_2.due_date AS due_date, anon_2.type AS type 
FROM (SELECT task.id AS task_id, user.signup_date AS due_date, ? AS type 
FROM task JOIN user ON task.id = user.task_id UNION ALL SELECT task.id AS task_id, schedule.due_date AS due_date, ? AS type 
FROM task JOIN schedule ON task.id = schedule.task_id) AS anon_2) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.due_date >= ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Creating a column definition directly inside the filter should work. You could try the following code:

```python
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    
    tasks.filter(sa.Column(sa.Date, name="due_date") >= datetime(2017, 4, 1))
```

or

```python
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import column
    
    tasks.filter(column("due_date") >= datetime(2017, 4, 1))
```